# mysql-slow.log how to find specific query SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM

Tags: mysql

Running this command:

```
mysqldumpslow -a -s r -t 30 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Gives me this:

```
Count: 1  Time=1346.85s (1346s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  
Rows_sent=237930890.0 (237930890), Rows_examined=237930890.0 
(237930890), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), user[user]@localhost
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `sometable`
```

**My goal is to find the slow query and fix it**.

I have searched for "* FROM `sometable`", "40001", "SQL_NO_CACHE", none of those are found in the source code.  Whats the deal?  All other queries, I can find no problem.

I realize that the count is 1.  That is because this is a relatively new log, the count will go up.

Comment: To make it more easy for next time configure MySQL to store slow logs in a [table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output) instead makes searching alot more easy..

Comment: No wonder it works slow when it has `237930890` rows

Comment: is `sometable` is real table name.. ? Who else got access to that MySQL server? As it is a bit wierd you can't find the query in your source code..

Comment: Are you sure the count will go up? The only obvious clue there is the user name: is that the user that your app uses? `select * from sometable` looks like the sort of thing a person would do when testing. Even if it is the same user your app uses it could be a person borrowing the credentials.

Comment: *"Other people have access to the server, I don't see how thats relevant."* it is not that unrelevant.. The question is why can't you find your table name in the application code maybe it is not used in the source code?  Maybe a old table which is not in use annymore? Did you consider those cases?

Comment: It could be mysqldump fetching the whole table to back it up? https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/82979/146656 (It sounds like mysqldump can count as slow queries.)

Comment: Raymond, I can find "sometable" in lets just say.. 10 different files for example.  Of those 10 files which one is it?  We don't ever do a 'SELECT *' on anything.

Comment: ok fair enough now you are giving beter details from reading the question/comments i got the impression that the table was never found in the source code.. (i've maybe have misread those)..  @Rup suggestion seams very possible..

Comment: @Rup suggestion is definitely a good one and I didn't know that about mysqldump.  That still may be possible...  However on another server, the count is 595.  So yes I am sure the count will eventually go up.

Comment: think @Rup is spot on here... mysqldump source code -> https://github.com/twitter-forks/mysql/blob/master/client/mysqldump.c#L3429 it adds the `/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */`

Comment: Ya I think so as well... https://github.com/twitter-forks/mysql/blob/master/client/mysqldump.c#L3476  Thats the exact string minus the table name.  Also there is a cronjob for mysqldump.  I'm pretty sure Rup is right on this.  I can verify, if tommorrow the count is two on all of those tables, that is enough evidence for me to conclude that Rup is right.

Comment: Consider looking at the input to the summary request for the complete content of the query in question.  While you NEVER SELECT *, it did this time.

Comment: @WilsonHauck What do you mean by 'summary request', and how do I go about it?  I can also confirm that Rup was correct in that mysqldump is creating those through crontab.  Today the count is 6.  The count was 1 when I started, it has been 5 days from then, 5+1 = 6.  Confirmed for me.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by @Rup.  mysqldump is running these queries and mysql is counting these as slow queries.

If you take a look at [mysqldump's source code](https://github.com/twitter-forks/mysql/blob/master/client/mysqldump.c#L3476) (Thanks Raymond), it has this code:

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM
```

Which is exactly what mysqldumpslow was returning.